# How to calculate the caret position in NanoVG?

Tags: java, text, lwjgl

I want to create a text area for my LWJGL 3 Game, and render it using NanoVG.nvgTextBox(), but I can't split my input string into wrapped lines that would be displayed on the screen, to then calculate the caret position.

My example:
If the screen shows up this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeYcr.png

I expected to get this String array: ["1 2 3 4 5 6", "7 8 9 10 11", "12"] (or something like that)

Edit:

Code:

```java
NanoVG.nvgBeginFrame(ctx, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight(), 1);
NanoVG.nvgBeginPath(ctx);
NanoVG.nvgFontFaceId(ctx, font);
NanoVG.nvgFillColor(ctx, NanoVG.nvgRGBAf(1, 1, 1, 1, NVGColor.create()));
NanoVG.nvgTextBox(ctx, 100, 100, 100, string);
String[] lines = //?;
NanoVG.nvgEndFrame(ctx);
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.